# Only one logo into the HTML5 API "drag and drop" box

Tags: html, css

As it sits right now, each logo will go into the box, but only the first into the box will show if more than one logo is placed there.  Is there a way to either (a) only allow one logo into the box, killing the ability for others to be dropped there or (b) after the first logo goes into the box, if a different logo is dropped into it, the first logo is replaced by the second (or third, or forth, etc)  Option B would be the preferred method.

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="pagepics/Avengers_Logo.png" draggable="true"ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Avengers Logo"  width="200" height="100">
<img id="drag2" src="pagepics/Ghostbusters.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Ghostbusters Logo"  width="200" height="100">
<img id="drag3" src="pagepics/ResidentEvil.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Resident Evil Logo" width="200" height="100">

#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
 }
```

Comment: Have you considered checking if the drop target has any children before blindly appending the dropped element?

Comment: @enhzflep The initial code I got from w3schools then slightly modified it so that there would be a choice of what to drag/drop.  When I tested it, I found that multiple logos could be dropped into the box with only the first one actually showing.  From what I can tell from the code, there are no children, but I won't swear to that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, all of the logos/images are showing when more than one logo is placed there. However, the height of the target box is only 70px, so it appears the images aren't inside it.

That said, the following solution will replace logos as you add new ones.

One last note, images and links are draggable by default, so it's not necessary to add the draggable attribute.

Hope this helps!

```js
function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id);
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var src = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
  var srcParent = src.parentNode;
  var itm = event.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

  event.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, itm);
  srcParent.appendChild(itm);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <span></span>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <img id="drag1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/180x100" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Avengers Logo">
<div>

<div class="box">
  <img id="drag2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Ghostbusters Logo">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img id="drag3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x100" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Resident Evil Logo">
</div>
```

Comment: Things like this always helps.  I do have one question though -- If the draggable attribute is not needed, why is it included in the W3schools code?  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: Maybe they're just being thorough in their example. But they do mention the default draggability of images and links in the HTML drag and drop API: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp. It certainly won't hurt anything if you do include it. Please be sure to upvote and mark as answered if this helped!

Comment: This is prob WAY too much to ask, but is there a way so that if one image is dragged into the box, then a different image is dragged there, the first image goes back to where it was located to begin with?

Comment: Depending on your use, you can adjust the parent nodes to get the result you want. I've edited the answer slightly so that each logo swaps positions with the added image, rather than simply than being appended to the end of a single parentNode.